# Change first byte of file in Linux?

Tags: linux, editing

How can I change the first byte of multiple files in Linux?  Willing to use `perl`/`awk`/`sed`/whatever.  This must work correctly on binary files (i.e. not change any other bytes).

Comment: are you sure you mean byte?  (a byte is a unit of data that is eight binary digits long).  If you change the first byte of a file Im guessing you will corrupt the file.  
Are you referring to changing the first char of the filename?

Comment: No, I meant what I said.  I need to invalidate the data for a bunch of torrents that my client has marked as completed, but the tracker doesn't agree.  I figure the best way is to change the data as little as possible and force my client to re-check the data.  Then it'll download at most one piece from each torrent, and tell the tracker the torrent is done.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
echo -ne \\xFF | dd conv=notrunc bs=1 count=1 of=$YOURFILE
```

> -n => do not output the trailing newline
> -e => enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Replacing `FF` with your hex value.

Try it first though :)

Comment: Nice and simple, works fine according to my testing.  Is that easily adaptable to changing a byte other than the first?  I played around with it a little but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @jnylen It should be adaptable to changing an arbitrary byte other than the first as well, the seek=<nblocks> option to dd is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Kjetil: thanks, that worked... I'd vote your comment up if I had 2 more reputation points :p

Answer (score -1):

compile this with `gcc -o w1stb w1stb.c` and use it like `./w1stb <file> <byte>`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

   int i;
   FILE* f;
   unsigned char b;

   if (argc < 3) {
       printf("usage: w <filename> <byte>\n");
       return 1;
   }

   i = atoi(argv[2]);

   if (i < 0) {
       printf("error, negative byte\n");
       return 2;
   }

   if (i > 255) {
       printf("error, to big byte\n");
       return 3;
   }

   f = fopen(argv[1], "w");
   if (!f) {
       printf("error, can't open file\n");
       return 4;
   }

   b = (unsigned char)i;
   fwrite(&b, 1, 1, f);
   fclose(f);

   return 0;
}
```